# Can running two versions of same library make system unstable

Tags: networking, apt

Can running two versions of same library make system unstable? Actually I was struggling to start the packet tracer in Ubuntu. In my search I found this tutorial

https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/ccna-study-guide/how-to-install-and-start-packet-tracer-in-ubuntu.html

It explains the reason and possible solution of my problem. By following instructions given in this tutorial I am able to start packet tracer in Ubuntu without any error in my test system.

The only concern I have is that it says “*The latest versions of libicui18n.so.52 and libicuuc.so.52 are already installed in Ubuntu. But packet tracer needs older versions of these libraries. Since the latest versions of these libraries are already installed in system we cannot install the older versions of these libraries from repositories through apt-get command. To solve this issue, we have to download the older versions of these libraries from external repository*.”

If I install the older versions of libicui18n.so.52 and libicuuc.so.52 in my production system, will they conflict with existing libraries?

I am new to linux.  Can any experienced Linux user suggest me a better way to keep two versions of same library without any conflict?

Comment: There are no conflicts by having more than one version of `libicu`. The library files have unique file names, each version. There are also examples of applications which require a specific libicu to build. "qtmltfs" https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/compiling-quantum-ltfs-software-on-debian-894103/#10

Answer (score 1):

> If I install the older versions of libicui18n.so.52 and libicuuc.so.52 in my production system, will they conflict with existing libraries?

How do you expect the regular software to know about this older version? It would if you could use `apt` (but it will refuse to install due to unmet dependencies). The way you do this is by manually copying libs. Those will only be touched by the software you want them for.

But in case you do have regular software where someone used the older libraries  only that bit of software might bug out. It will be pretty local so easy to fix. Worth noting I would consider that a bug; the old lib has no place in that software.

Do contact the creator of packet tracer to update their software.